# What is the transformation group of a direct product (trivial group extension)?

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

In "Group Extensions and Homology" Eilenberg and Mac Lane define

$$Ext\ (G,H) =Fact\ (G,H)/Trans\ (G,H)$$

for a normal subgroup $H$ that extends the group $G$. The trivial case of $H$ that extends the group $G$ is for example:
$$ 1 \rightarrow 
(\mathbb{R}, \cdot) \rightarrow 
(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}, \cdot) \rightarrow 
(\mathbb{R}, \cdot) \rightarrow 
1$$

Now, E & M also define a transformation as satisfying
$$ t(h,k)=g(h)+g(k)-g(h+k)  $$
for a group under addition where $h,k \in H$ and $g(h), g(k) \in G$

Allowing $f(x)=x$ to be a function in $(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}, \cdot)$ above, this gives me $1$, making $Trans(G,H)$ the trivial group which makes sense if (as other sources say) the transformation group is the permutation group or group of automorphisms.

Now my problem is this correlates to the following for me, which makes no sense
$$Ext\ (G,H) =Fact\ (G,H)/Trans\ (G,H)$$
$$(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}, \cdot) =
(\mathbb{R}, \cdot)/(1,\cdot)$$

What am I doing wrong in terms of the groups? Also, I have no reason to believe it does, but if my mistake relates to homology, I should warn you that I do not understand homology yet.

Comment: The set $\mathrm{Fact}(G,H)$ consists of all functions $f\colon \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ that satisfy $f(h,k)=f(k,h)$ and $f(h,k) + f(h+k,\ell) = f(h,k+\ell) + f(k,\ell)$. Why is the group of all such functions is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ under multiplication? What functions corresponds to which real number?

Comment: @Arturo Magidin Thank you for taking the time to help me. I appreciate it. I conflated the group over the factor sets, Fact($G,H$), with the factor group itself (the reals under multiplication). Are these functions in the factor set strong enough to determine that the underlying set for Fact($G,H$) is $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Also note that $\mathrm{Ext}(G,H)$ is supposed to give **all** extensions (up to isomorphism of extensions) of $G$ by $H$, so here, it would be all extensions of $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ by $\mathbb{R}$. And in this context, $\mathrm{Trans}(G,H)$" is not "the transformation group", which means something else entirely; it is the group of "transformations" (here a term of art defined as functions $H\times H\to G$ satisfying the given property), not the "group of automorphisms" (of what?)

Comment: The "underlying set" $\mathrm{Frac}(G,H)$ is the set of all functions as I described; $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ is not a set of functions $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ satisfying the given conditions, so it cannot be the case that the "underlying set for $\mathrm{Fact}(G,H)$ is $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$." It may be the case that the **group** (under addition) $\mathrm{Fact}(G,H)$ is *isomorphic* to $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ (under... addition, I guess?), but that would require providing an actual isomorphism.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin Your second comment clarifies everything. This makes far more sense. I was conflating all of these sets with the neologisms describing groups. Eilenberg and Mac Lane have beautiful architecture on this. Thank you again. To clarify: I believed the transformations were the automorphisms on the underlying set assuming some higher structure, but as you have shown, I was mistaken.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin A side note: I was thinking $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ under addition is isomorphic to the set of functions under addition given they both have something of a linear structure. But, I think my intuition here is a bit of a stretch and clearly missed the mark as to Mac Lane and Eilenberg's intentions.

Comment: I think part of the problem is that you are confusing certain terms; the collection of "factor sets" $\mathrm{Fact}(G,H)$ is not the same thing as the quotient group $G/H$ (which perhaps you were thinking of as a "factor group"?) and the collection of "transformations from $H$ to $G$", $\mathrm{Tran}(G,H)$ is not the group of transformations of a structure (automorphisms). The nomenclature is unfortunate and no doubt does not help. Both of these collections are sets of functions satisfying specific, explicit properties.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin that is exactly what happened. The nomenclature caught me off. This also makes more sense in terms of the latter formulation Ext($G,H$) $\cong$ Hom($R,G$) / Hom($F | R,G$) for $H=F/R$ a factor group where $F$ is free. I can understand these now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Prof. Arturo Magidin kindly pointed out, $Ext$, $Trans$, and $Fact$ represent the collections whose elements satisfy Mac Lane and Eilenberg's definitions for and extension of $G$ by $H$ where $h,k,l\in H$ and
$$t(h,k)\in Fact$$
$$t(h,k)=g(h)+g(k)-g(h+k)$$
Which, these $t$ always satisfy the conditions for the elements $f \in Fact$ s.t.
$$f(h,k) +f(h+k,l)=f(h,k+l)+f(k,l) \\ f(h,k) =f(k,h)$$

Where, these collections form groups. But, the groups formed are not to be confused with common notions of transformation groups and factor (or quotient) groups.

This gives the result for $\mathrm{Ext}\{G,H\}$ the *group of group extensions* of $G$ by $H$ for $\mathrm{Fact}\{G,H\}$ group of all factor sets and $\mathrm{Trans}\{G,H\}$ group of all transformation sets.

$$\mathrm{Ext}\{G,H\} = \mathrm{Fact}\{G,H\} / \mathrm{Trans}\{G,H\}$$

I answered this to close the question and give a succinct response for future readers, but all credit of explanation goes to Prof. Arturo Magidin.

Comment: Can you give some examples for Fact, Trans computing Ext?